# What does a gradlew do

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

I got a project which was a eclipse project. And now I'm using Android Studio with gradle 2.2.1. I've found that when I create a project with Android Studio, it will generate a gradlew file, and it may include some CLI functions. But when I transfer my project from eclipse to Android Studio, I didn't find my gradlew file.
So, here is my question: what does a gradlew file exactly do? Can it be customized?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**gradlew** is for *gradle wrapper* which can let your project independent with the environment. For example, in CI server, if your project brings gradle wrapper, then you don't have to install gradle in the environment.

If you create a project with android studio, it will generate gradle wrapper into your project by default.

You can see more information in [Gradle wrapper](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)